# How to increase performance of Azure Data Factory Pipeline with Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to increated the performance of our pipelines.

The pipelines currently run from an integration runtime.

I am running a single copy activity on tables held on our Source which is a SQL Database. Tables contain just under a million rows, with about 15 columns.

Currently the time it takes to copy a table from Source to Sink(ADLS) is approximately 20mins.

Is there a way to increase the DIU to increase performance?

My current copy settings are as follows:

[image]

[image]

I'm thinking that if I made some changes to Settings, see below, I would improve performance, but I have never played around to settings before, any suggestions most welcomed.

[image]

The activity details for a pipeline run is as follows:

[image]

My link service is an Azure Synapse Link service, see below:

[image]

Comment: please provide a screenshot of the activity output details (when you click on the glasses), so we can see where is the delay.

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, thanks for reaching out. Sorry for the delayed response. I have updated the question with the activity output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output window, we can see that almost all the wait time was "Time to first byte", which means your SQL server is slow to reply. It takes ~22 minutes for less than 90K rows. So changes on the ADF side will not help.
If your query is a simple "select * from table", then maybe your SQL server is low on resources. You can check that in your database portal in Azure. Try to add more resources and see if copy times improve.
If this is a query from a view or other complicated query, maybe it needs some improvement (indexes, improve code). You can test that by writing the query result to a table in your SQL database, use that table as the data factory source, and see if this improves copy time.

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, thanks again for reaching. This wasn't the answer I was looking for, but if that is what it is, then so be it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I extracting the data from Azure SQL Serverless Pool, and I don't think its possible to increase the resources on SQL Serverless Pool ... maybe that is a question I should add to SO

Comment: @Patterson ,  Do you mean Azure database serverless (not provisioned) or serverless pool in synapse?

Comment: Hi @ChehHirsh, I mean serverless pool in synapse

Comment: Try in ADF to use a linked service of type "Azure synapse analytics" as your source. It looks from your screenshots that you are using "Azure SQL database" Linked service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, I am using and Azure Synapse Link service. See updated question

Comment: @Patterson , when you run the same query in Synapse, does it still run that long? If so, maybe you should check this document about best practices in Synapse serverless pool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-serverless-sql-pool

Answer (score 0):

Quick check , is the Azure SQL and storage account in the same region ? Also I see that your copy activity is set as parraleism as 1 , you can play with number and see if that helps .

How to setyp parallelism please read here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#parallel-copy

Please see the snaphot below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Himan, can you explain what parallel copies achieve.

Comment: I did update my answer above.